# PHP isn't updating with the MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

The code below shows my connection to reach my MYSQL Database, but for some reason once it grabs the details from the database it doesn't update the PHP page after that. As an example, currently the table lastWinner is a string datatype which contains "David". After saving the php file the output shows as David, but if I change the value in the mysql database the output doesn't change afterwards.

```
  <div id="navigation">
     <?php
       $host     = "localhost";
       $username = "DB_USER";
       $password = "PASSWORD";
       $db_name  = "DB_NAME";
       $message = "The last person to win the lottery is: ";
       mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die (mysql_error ());
       mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysql_error());               
       $total = "SELECT lastWinner AS total FROM info";
       $rs = mysql_query($total);                                                                                              
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
             echo $message.$row['total'];
       }                                                        
       mysql_close();
    ?>
  </div>
```

Heres the code that sends the data to the database itself.

```
  public static boolean updateInfo() {
    try {
        if (Settings.DisableMYSQL == true)
            return false;
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        if (Lottery.getCurrentLotteryWinner() == null
                && Lottery.getLastLotteryWinner() == null)
            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE info SET lastWinner = 'There current isn't a lottery winner!'");
        else if (Lottery.getCurrentLotteryWinner() != null
                && Lottery.getLastLotteryWinner() == null)
            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE info SET lastWinner = '"
                    + Lottery.getCurrentLotteryWinner() + "'");
        else
            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE info SET lastWinner = '"
                    + Lottery.getLastLotteryWinner() + "'");

            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE info SET moneyEarned = '"
                + Lottery.options.size() + "'");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastConnection > 10000) {
            destroyConnection();
            createConnection();
            lastConnection = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the browser is caching the page? Try adding a cache-buster parameter.

Comment: can you show us the code where you are saving/changing the value(s)?

Comment: @Barmar I tried that, but deleting all cache, cookies, etc didn't work.

Comment: @zzlalani I added it to the thread.

Comment: The issue is where you are saving the records not where you are showing them, if you could show us the code where you saved/changed the record, we might help you

Comment: If you run the query by hand, does it return the new value?

Comment: The problem is almost definitely autocommit. You are probably using an InnoDB table, and your autocommit is set to off, and you aren't manually committing, so nothing is getting shown. Look that up and see where it gets you.

Comment: @Barmar No it doesn't I tried it 
&zzlalani I'm saving it in a table using mysql

Comment: If the query doesn't work when you run it by hand, then why do you expect it to work in PHP? It's probably the problem Henry described.

Comment: @Barmar when you say run it by hand I thought you meant changing the values myself >.> I'm looking into what he said now.

Comment: @DavidPace what Barmar is trying to ask is that did you try it by changing the value directly with in the mysql table from phpmyadmin or any other source?

Comment: I meant running the `SELECT` query by hand.

Comment: And the mysql table type is: MyISAM

Comment: ofcourse `SELECT` query

Comment: what Barmar is trying to ask is that did you try it by changing the value directly with in the mysql table from phpmyadmin or any other source? - Yes I did, the value changes in the mysql table but not on the php page though, and like I said the mysql table type is MylSAM

Comment: Also the autocommit returns as 1, which I believe means its enabled.

Comment: you updated the row in mysql manually and nothing changes at the front in php page?

Comment: @ZZlalani Yes I updated the mysql manually, and the php didn't change from the last result.

Comment: I think you have two different databases with the same structure.

Comment: There's only one database with a table and two columns

Answer (score 0):

My webhost was having difficulties and did something which made it work.